# React-Query: How to useQuery when button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-query

I am new to this [react-query](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query) library.

I know that when I want to fetch data, with this library I can do something like this:

```
const fetchData = async()=>{...}

// it starts fetching data from backend with this line of code
const {status, data, error} = useQuery(myKey, fetchData());
```

It works. But how to trigger the data fetching only when a button is clicked? , I know I probably could do something like `<Button onPress={() => {useQuery(myKey, fetchData())}}/>` , but how to manage the returned data and status...

Answer (score 211):

According to the [API Reference](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery), you need to change the `enabled` option to **false** to disable a query from automatically running. Then you refetch manually.

```js
// emulates a fetch (useQuery expects a Promise)
const emulateFetch = _ => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve([{ data: "ok" }]);
  });
};

const handleClick = () => {
  // manually refetch
  refetch();
};

const { data, refetch } = useQuery("my_key", emulateFetch, {
  refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  enabled: false // disable this query from automatically running
});

return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    {JSON.stringify(data)}
  </div>
);
```

Working sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactquery-manual-refetch-d16m9)

Bonus: you can pass anything that returns a boolean to `enabled`.
That way you could create Dependant/Serial queries.

```js
// Get the user
const { data: user } = useQuery(['user', email], getUserByEmail)
 
// Then get the user's projects
const { isIdle, data: projects } = useQuery(
  ['projects', user.id],
  getProjectsByUser,
  {
    // `user` would be `null` at first (falsy),
    // so the query will not execute until the user exists
    enabled: user,
  }
)
```

Comment: second time api call not wotking on button click

Comment: Probably out-of-scope of this question. Check codesandbox and add console.logs in different parts (resolve, button, etc). It works more than once. Probably something else in your component is not working. Use [devtools](https://react-query.tanstack.com/devtools) and check how your cached responses act (are they refreshing when you click your button?)

Comment: check in console too its not working  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue9Z9.png

Comment: That is an unrelated api call from codesandbox, not from my code. The example has no actual API calls because it's an emulated fetch api. I'm actually just returning a promise (hence `emulateFetch ` name). React-query expects a promise, and since this was just an example it made sense to be hacky and not expect an actual response from free apis which might fail in the future and leave a future user with the same doubt without knowing what is going on. Check my example again, I've added a log.

Comment: Why not using useMutation instead of useQuery?

Comment: If it helps someone, `refetch()` returns a promise and can resolve it to get the data of the response if you want to do something synchronously.

Comment: We cannot use mutations for a get call, we can use them for put/post/delete calls

https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/mutations

Comment: As per the API reference, you can use `useLazyQuery` for example: 

``
...
const [getLogin, { loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery("login", LOGIN_USER)
...
return(
            <Button onClick={getLogin()} />
)
``

Comment: I need to call the refect on input change event is it possible to do that

Comment: @ADB I can't find anything in the documentation that says "useMutation cannot be used with get request", can you point me to the right place?

Comment: I read it somewhere on this blog, if you got time please checkout this blog: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query

Comment: I didn't want to comment because the comment list is big enough, but from Tanner: "The difference is the flow of data. useQuery is used to query async data, useMutation is used to mutate it. Or in the traditional CRUD speak: Read: useQuery Create/Update/Delete: useMutation".

Comment: It would be reasonable to want to change the parameters of the query when the button is clicked too. But this doesn't look supported.

Comment: This works but is [not recommended by the primary maintainer](https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/5820#discussioncomment-6604337).  Instead use `queryClient.fetchQuery()`

Answer (score 29):

You have to pass the `manual: true` parameter option so the query doesn't fetch on mount. Also, you should pass `fetchData` without the parentheses, so you pass the function reference and not the value. 
To call the query you use refetch().

```
const {status, data, error, refetch} = useQuery(myKey, fetchData, {
      manual: true,
    });

const onClick = () => { refetch() }
```

Refer to the manual querying section on the react-query docs for more info
https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query#manual-querying

Comment: I think "manual" (that still exists) is replaced by "enabled"(in V2). https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query#disabling-or-pausing-a-query

Answer (score 19):

Looks like the documentation changed and is missing the manual querying section right now. Looking at the useQuery API however, you'd probably need to set `enabled` to false, and then use `refetch` to manually query when the button is pressed. You also might want to use `force: true` to have it query regardless of data freshness.

Answer (score 10):

There are two problems with `refetch()`:

- it will send a request to the server even if the response is already cached and the `staleTime` has not expired
- you can't pass params to it

If you need to make a query on an event like `onClick` or `onChange`, use [`queryClient.fetchQuery()`](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientfetchquery).

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const handleOnClick = async () => {
    const data = await queryClient.fetchQuery({ queryKey, queryFn });
  }

  return <button onClick={handleOnClick}>My Button</button>;
}
```

You can see the [creator](https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/1549#discussioncomment-287283) and [current maintainer](https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/5820#discussioncomment-6604337) recommending this approach.

Answer (score 8):

At first react query gives us enabled option and by default it is true

```
const fetchData = async()=>{...}

const {status, data, error , refetch} = useQuery(myKey, fetchData() , {
enabled : false
}
);

<button onClick={() => refetch()}>Refetch</button>
```

Comment: r u sure that enabled is true by default?

Comment: Yah if enabled is not true then how can react query fetch data in initial render look up to react query docs they purely assign that enabled is true it is pretty common right cause we always want the data in initial render so enabled is always true.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this version:

```
const fetchData = async()=>{...}

// it starts fetching data from backend with this line of code
const {status, data, error, refetch } = useQuery(
myKey, 
fetchData(),
{
  enabled: false,
}
);
const onClick = () => { refetch() }
// then use onClick where you need it
```

From documentation [Doc](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery):

`enabled: boolean`

- Set this to false to disable this query from automatically running.
- Can be used for Dependent Queries.

`refetch: (options: { throwOnError: boolean, cancelRefetch: boolean }) => Promise<UseQueryResult>`

- A function to manually refetch the query.
- If the query errors, the error will only be logged. If you want an error to be thrown, pass the `throwOnError: true option`
- If `cancelRefetch` is `true`, then the current request will be cancelled before a new request is made

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to do this that also works if you want to trigger multiple refetches.

```js
const [fetch, setFetch] = useState(null);
const query = useQuery(["endpoint", fetch], fetchData);

const refetch = () => setFetch(Date.now());

// call the refetch when handling click.
```

If you want to refetch multiple entities you could have a top level useState that is called for instance fetchAll and:

```js
...
const query = useQuery(["endpoint", fetch, fetchAll], fetchData);
...
```

and this code will also trigger if you press a button to fetch all.

Comment: sadly Not work!
It's not refetch if the `fetch` changes

Comment: @OliverD I'm using this, so most likely you have some other issue

Answer (score 2):

If the key is the same, then use refetch(), if the key is different then use useState to trigger the query.

For example:

```
const [productId, setProductId] = useState<string>('')
const {status, data, error, refetch} = useQuery(productId, fetchData, {
      enable: !!productId,
    });

const onClick = (id) => { 
if(productId === id) {
  refetch() 
}
else {
 setProductId(id)
}


}
```

Comment: not enable but enabled

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others in this thread, using `query.refetch` does make a request even if the cache is not stale. So ideally, we would not call `query.refetch` only if `query.isFetched && !query.isStale`. I wanted to encapsulate that logic inside a hook and this is how I solved it:

```
// useGetFoo.ts
export const useGetFoo = () => {
  const query = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["foo"],
    queryFn: fetcher,
    enabled: false,
  });

  const fetch = (): ReturnType<typeof query.refetch> => {
    if (query.isFetching) return Promise.resolve(query);
    if (query.isFetched && !query.isStale && !query.isError)
      // browser hangs without this setTimeout
      return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(query)));
    return query.refetch();
  };

  return { ...query, fetch };
};
```

And then we can use it like this:

```
// SomeComponent.tsx
const { data, fetch: getFoo } = useGetFoo();

useEffect(() => {
  void getFoo();
}, [getFoo]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In **react-query** there is an option for **useQuery()** to trigger the hook whenever you want. The option is **enabled** which only takes boolean. Here's an example:

```
const useGetAllUsers = useQuery({
    queryKey:["users"],
    queryFn: your_fetch_request,
    enabled: true|false
})
```

you can pass any boolean state from that component here.

Answer (score 0):

User query on click is it will only fetch the data when user click or user allow Earlier any website will fetch data by default whenever you use axios for get data now userquery on click help to fetch data only when you clicked on a button so for this you have to do 2 things

1. Use Usequery for fetching data by disabling the button for default fetching
2. Usequery gives you one thing refetch which will help you below is the code

```
const fetchSuperHeroes=()=>{
return axios.get("localhost:4000/superheroes")
const {isLoadind,data,error,isError,refetch}=useQuery('super-heroes',fetchSuperHeroes{
enable:false
}
```

Answer (score -12):

you can use useLazyQuery()

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLazyQuery } from '@apollo/client';

function DelayedQuery() {
   const [getDog, { loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_DOG_PHOTO);

   if (loading) return <p>Loading ...</p>;
   if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;

   return (
      <div>
         {data?.dog && <img src={data.dog.displayImage} />}
         <button onClick={() => getDog({ variables: { breed: 'bulldog' } })}>Click me!</button>
      </div>
   );
}
```

reference: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#manual-execution-with-uselazyquery

Comment: This is wrong answer because it uses apollo client which is a different library from react-query and doesnt apply in this context. Plus that is graphql the question is for REST API.