# Cannot call useQuery inside event handler (react-query, react-hook-form)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, react-query

I have to call useQuery inside event handler. (user registration) and Im trying something like this.

```js
const [postUser, { isError, isLoading, data }] = useQuery('user', () =>
    axios.post(API_URL, { query: GET_TOKEN_QUERY }).then((res) => res.data)
  )

  const openModalCallback = React.useCallback(
    (modalName) => {
      onOpenModal(modalName)
    },
    [onOpenModal]
  )

  async function onSubmit(data: LoginInputs) {
    if (data.checkbox) {
      postUser()
    }
  }
```

But I get an error like this and cant resolve it. Help me please.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Query: How to useQuery when button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340697/react-query-how-to-usequery-when-button-is-clicked)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create/update/delete data or perform server side-effects (opposed to just read data from server), better use [`useMutation`](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useMutation).

The hook returns a `mutate()` function which you can call `onSubmit()`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply post the data with the `useQuery` hook, for that you have to use the `useMutation()` hook and it returns a function which you can call inside an event handler.