# How to run useQueries only after clicking a button in react-query?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

```
export const useDeleteArticles = ({ ids, onSuccess }) => {
  const queryResult = useQueries(
    ids.map(id => ({
      queryKey: ["article-delete", id],
      queryFn: () => articlesApi.destroy(id),
    }))
  );

  const isLoading = queryResult.some(result => result.isLoading);

  if (!isLoading) {
    onSuccess();
  }

  return { isLoading, queryResult };
};
```

This customHook will simply delete some articles.

I tried to use `enabled` with a state as following.

```
export const useDeleteArticles = ({ ids, onSuccess, enabled }) => {
  const queryResult = useQueries(
    ids.map(id => ({
      queryKey: ["article-delete", id],
      queryFn: () => articlesApi.destroy(id),
      enabled,
    }))
  );

  const isLoading = queryResult.some(result => result.isLoading);

  if (!isLoading) {
    onSuccess();
  }

  return { isLoading, queryResult };
};
```

```
const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);
useDeleteArticles({ ids, onSuccess: refetch, enabled });

enabled && setEnabled(false);    //to avoid api call after deleting the articles

const handleArticleDelete = () => {    //this function will invoke onClick button
    setEnabled(true);
};
```

But this not making the api call.
could anyone help me to implement this in correct way.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Query: How to useQuery when button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340697/react-query-how-to-usequery-when-button-is-clicked)

Comment: Isn't [useMutation](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/mutations) more suitable for your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

> This customHook will simply delete some articles.

a delete operation is almost never a query, but a `mutation`. Mutations can be fired imperatively by calling the `mutate` function returned from `useMutation`. A query is the wrong thing to use for this.