# Component won't render on submit

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query

Hope you can help me with this. So I am trying to use IP address to get latitude and longitude and therefore get a location on a map when an new IP is submitted using `axios` and `react-query` but can't find out what am I doing wrong.
I tried with only useState and then setting `setIp(data);` to `handleSubmit` but it didn't work as well.
I always get `undefined` data when refresh page so I handled that like this `{ geoData && <CreateMap ...`

Is it even right approach with react-query? Is this how I fetch the data?
Thank you for your help!

I have 2 components called Input and CreateMap.

Input.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import CreateMap from "./CreateMap";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const InputComponent = () => {
  const [ip, setIp] = useState("8.8.8.8");
  const [geoData, setGeoData] = useState();

  const { isLoading, isError, data, error } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["posts"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=e1ba80b5c7a64f0fb61db1f286d78562&ip=${ip}`
        );
        return response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
      }
    },
  });

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }
  if (isError) {
    return <h1>Error: {error.message}</h1>;
  }

  const handleIpChange = (e) => {
    setIp(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setGeoData(data)
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>Write your IP address: </label>
      <input type="text" defaultValue={ip} onChange={handleIpChange} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      { geoData && <CreateMap lat={geoData.latitude} lng={geoData.longitude} /> }
    </form>
  );
};

export default InputComponent;
```

CreateMap.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import { Icon } from "leaflet";

import "./Map.css";


const CreateMap = ({ lat, lng }) => {
 
  return (
    <div>
        <MapContainer
          style={{ height: "480px", width: "100%" }}
          center={[lat, lng]}
          zoom={12}
        >
          <TileLayer
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          />
        </MapContainer>
    </div>

  );
};

export default CreateMap;
```

and App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Input from './components/Input'


const App = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>App</h1>
      <Input />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: I think you should refetch manually. Check these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340697/react-query-how-to-usequery-when-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should be good with the `refetch` from `react-query`

```
const InputComponent = () => {
  const [ip, setIp] = useState("8.8.8.8");

  const { isLoading, isError, data, error, refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["posts"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=e1ba80b5c7a64f0fb61db1f286d78562&ip=${ip}`
        );
        return response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
      }
    },
    enabled: false
  });

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }
  if (isError) {
    return <h1>Error: {error.message}</h1>;
  }

  const handleIpChange = (e) => {
    setIp(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    refetch();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>Write your IP address: </label>
      <input type="text" defaultValue={ip} onChange={handleIpChange} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      { data && <CreateMap lat={data.latitude} lng={data.longitude} /> }
    </form>
  );
};
```

For the rerender, create a control component :

```
function UpdateCenter({ center }) {
  const map = useMap();
  map.setView(center);
  return null;
}
```

And add it in your CreateMap :

```
const CreateMap = ({ lat, lng }) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <MapContainer
          style={{ height: "480px", width: "100%" }}
          center={[lat, lng]}
          zoom={12}
          
        >
          <TileLayer
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          />
          <UpdateCenter center={[lat, lng]} />
        </MapContainer>
    </div>

  );
};
```

Comment: OK, that looks better and I do get latitude and longitude on other component through props when submit new ip address but why doesn't CreateMap component re-render? Correct me if I am wrong but when state is changed component should re-render, right?

Comment: Check the edit. It does render but it's the MapContainer that doesn't want to update the center. You need to add another component

Comment: why do we need another component to update the center? is this specifically for react-leaflet? or because I used react-query to fetch the api? thank you for your help and answers!

Comment: It is due to react-leaflet