# useQuery Hook - Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs

How to resolve `useQuery Hook error - Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`, I'm calling the `useQuery` hook inside the button click event function and I'm getting the above error I'm not sure how to call in onclick event like my below example code and I'm very new to react js.

I know  Hooks should only be called from the top level of a functional component, not within nested functions but my scenario the `useQuery` hook should call on onclick event like below my code.

Please refer my code and suggest me where I did the mistake and how to achieve this concept.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { getResend } from './dashboardQuery';

function View() {
        const handleClickResend = (ip1, ip2) => {
        console.info('You clicked the Chip.', ip1, ip2);

        const payload = { ip1: ip1, ip2: ip2 };
        const { isLoading, error, data, refetch } = getResend({ payload });
        console.log("isLoading :-", isLoading);
        console.log("data.data :-", data.data);

    };

 return (
<>

<Box sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
<Chip sx={{ color: "#003968", fontSize: fontsize, fontWeight: fontweightbold, bgcolor: "#EEF5F9" }}
label="Resend" onClick={(e) => { handleClickResend(row.ip1, row.ip2) }} />
</Box>

</>
);


}
export default View;
```

This function I'm calling

[image: working]

Comment: The code shown doesn't call `useQuery`.  And it sounds like you already know the reason for the error message and how to resolve it.  It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Why do you think you need to call `useQuery` inside of a click handler?

Comment: Hi @David , Because, when I click on  the `Chip` `handleClickResend(row.ip1, row.ip2)` at that time only some action should work like that my requirement is there for that I have written logic like this and in the `handleClickResend(row.ip1, row.ip2)` function I'm calling the `getResend({ payload });` function and in this function I'm using the `useQuery' & 'Axios' for output return `I added img please check once` and able to getting the output but if call this `getResend({ payload });` function inside the onclick function I'm getting the above error. Hope you understood my requirement.

Comment: This sounds like what you're looking for: [React-Query: How to useQuery when button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62340697/328193)